# Where is msbuild configured for a VB.NET application in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

This is a very, very basic question. Where do I specify MSBuild parameters for VB.Net applications in Visual Studio 2022?

- I have a VB.NET application that I am developing using Visual Studio 2022. I have an intermittent MSBuild error:

> `MSbuild error child node 2 exited prematurely. shutting down...`

- I would like to add the `/nodeReuse:false` to the `MSbuild` command, but cannot figure out where or how to specify MSBuild settings.
- I think these can be set in the XML of the project file, but have not found a clear reference on this.

### What I have found thus far:

1. I have not found a way to set `MSBuild` parameters in a `*proj` file. This would be a good solution as it would store the `MSBuild` parameters for each target with the project(s).
2. You can set a `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1` environment variable for `Windows 10`. This should be the same as `/nodeReuse:false`. However, this should be changed if you `/nodeReuse:true` is needed.
3. In his much appreciated comment below, Hans Passant recommends:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "maximum number of parallel project builds" = 1

4. In going through the Event Viewer, I found that our network anti-malware application caught the following:

> msbuild.exe attempted to replace the base executable code in the process "\?\globalroot\Device\NamedPipe...

This is an indication of a fileless attempt to deliver a remote access tool.

5. A useful comment from Jonathan Dodds on `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE` environment variable the is below.
6. As a test, I took the same Visual Studio solution that is throwing the intermittent `MSbuild error child node 2 exited prematurely. shutting down...` error in Visual Studio 2022 and rebuilt in Visual Studio 2017. After five rebuild-alls, no errors are thrown and CarbonBlack is not logging any issues in the application log.

- No CarbonBlack issues that were logged from Visual Studio 2022 MSBuild have been logged when the same solution is built with Visual Studio 2017.
- No `MSbuild error child node 2 exited prematurely. shutting down...` errors have occurred when the same solution is built in Visual Studio 2017.

> Even so, **Visual Studio 2022 cannot be declared as the definitive cause**. Testing and research needs to be done to determine if this is a legitimate issue reported by CarbonBlack or a false positive. Possible causes include:

- A false-positive from CarbonBlack
- The combination of Visual Studio 2022 and other settings.
- A legitimate fileless RAT using MSBuild to deliver `Remcos RAT` or other payloads as described by:

https://www.anomali.com/blog/threat-actors-use-msbuild-to-deliver-rats-filelessly

A Design of Experiments (DOE) could be useful to sort this out.

> A DOE is a structured approach that can determine the single factor or combination of two-or-more factors causing an issue. Testing often follows the logic of changing one thing at time. However, this cannot identify cases where problems are caused by the combination of two-or-more factors.

Comment: A quick google returned this link for a doc issue on the nodereuse command line flag: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2916  I see a couple of different strategies within which you may be able to use.  None will be accessible through the IDE, it looks like the two viable options are an environment variable or something you'll need to manually edit into your project file.

Comment: Manually adding the command line flag to the VBproj would be perfectly fine. I have not been able to find any references on adding an MSBuild flag to a VBproj or CSproj file. Most references show basics of *proj editing. An example on setting this in a *proj file would be useful (if this is even possible).

Comment: Nothing that I discussed had anything to do with "adding the command line flag".  Did you read the link?

Comment: You may consider [Reporting the Problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report)

Comment: Your first sentence is: 

> A quick google returned this link for a doc issue on the nodereuse **command line flag**. 

As I mentioned above, I would like to add the `/nodeReuse:false` to `MSBuild`. If I could do this by editing the VBproj file (so that I could still use the Visual Studio 2020 build, that would be good. - it would save documentation of a custom build procedure.

Comment: It is a machine stability problem, best to address it.  Anti-malware is always on the top of the list.  A workaround is Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "maximum number of parallel project builds" = 1

Comment: Regarding "If I could [disable `nodeReuse`] by editing the VBproj file ...", a project can't change the `nodeReuse` value for itself. The 'nodes' are used to load, evaluate, and execute the project. Changing the number of nodes from within the very code being processed by the nodes is not supported. (You can set the `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE` environment variable to 1 and spawn a new process that inherits the environment but that's not the same.)

Comment: Yes - I noticed that the `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE` environment variable to 1 and spawning a new process did not address the intermittent issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with Carbon Black(CB) stopping our builds from running when using MSBuild

My problem Azure DevOps saying:
`This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software`

For us to get our builds to function short of disabling CB on our build machine, we had to make an exception for the PathFunctions.ps1 script found here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers

I'm not sure why this script is picked up by CB but juts allowing this through fixed my issue